# HTML php preselected option value loaded in dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm struggling with something simple, I found a similar question on Stack but I couldn't make the solution work.

I have a html/php form to edit user's details. Because it is editing already existing information, a dropdown needs to pre-load a user's organisation from the mysql database. Because of db normalisation I put the organisation details in a separate table to the users table, so the user's record just holds their organisation's id.

The code fetches the user's info and populates the form for editing, but I can't get the organisation dropdown to display the user's organisation. I need it to have pre-selected the user's organisation (if applicable), but still have the list of options to alter it.

```
<td align="right">Organisation:</td>
            <td>
            <select name="user_org">
                <option>Select the organisation</option>

                <?php

                    //query to get the organisations from the db
                    $get_org = "SELECT * FROM organisations";

                    $run_org = mysqli_query($con, $get_org);

                   while ($row_org=mysqli_fetch_array($run_org)){

                        $org_id = $row_org['org_id'];
                        $org_name = $row_org['org_name'];


                    echo "<option value='$org_id';>$org_name</option>";
                    }?>


            </select>
```

Comment: Please copy the full code so we can see the form submit method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pick an option to be the selected one by default with [the "selected" attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp). In your situation, you can just check within the loop whether or not the current organization is the user's one. And add the "selected" attribute when it is.

For example, let's say  your user's organization id is stored in a variable `user_org`.

```
while ($row_org=mysqli_fetch_array($run_org)){
    $org_id = $row_org['org_id'];
    $org_name = $row_org['org_name'];

    echo "<option value='$org_id'";
    if($org_id === $user_org) echo " selected";
    echo ">$org_name</option>" . PHP_EOL;
}?>
```

Then, if an organization has an id that matches the user's one, the option will be selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
while ($row_org=mysqli_fetch_array($run_org))
{
    $org_id = $row_org['org_id'];
    $org_name = $row_org['org_name'];

    $selected = '';
    if( $org_id == $already_selected_value )
    {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    }

    echo <option value="'.$org_id.'" '.$selected.'>'.$org_name.'</option>';
}
```

**Explanation:** Initially `$selected` is blank but when condition becomes true, its value set the `selected` attribute of `option` to make that option default selected.